# ASP.Net: Load Advertise after load page? // performance Issues

Tags: asp.net, performance

I have a big performance issue in my asp.net page.
I have around 10-15 database querys on every page load, the page load is done in ~0,x seconds (very fast I think).

Since I add my advertisment:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                            adscale_slot_id = "xxxxx";
                        </script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.adscale.de/getads.js"></script>
```

My site-performance is very very high, it is around 1-2 seconds every page.

How to make it faster?

A idea is to load the advertise after the page is ready and loaded.
Is that do-able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defer is one way to load ads after page has loaded. Other way is to use ASWIFT way which uses iframe to load ads parallel. Google uses this way to speed up their page loading. It has a few gotchas but worth the try.

Check out this presentation by them on Velocityconf. [Don't let third parties slow you down](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2010/public/schedule/detail/15412)

--Sai

Comment: I see the video but don't understand 100% whats to do now and how to build it. Can you add more information about ASWIFT or a how to?

Comment: ASWIFT is based on loading the ad or third party widgets as different documents by iframe. iframe lets you do async loading of ad which will not block your page from loading..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the defer attribute to your script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.adscale.de/getads.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

This tells the browser to execute the script AFTER the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

### Load ads after page has loaded

When your advertisements are on a different web server it's always wise to load them after page has loaded. This way they won't slow down your page. If you use standard ad sizes, make sure your containers are appropriately sized so your page content won't reposition after ads load.

### Advertisements loading

You can either load them on page ready by Javascript DOM manipulation (in jQuery that would be `$(function(){ /* load */});`) or use the `DEFER` script attribute on the tag itself.

The first being more powerful and the latter being simpler.